# MegaCLI / MegaRAID Drive Groups

Tags: megaraid, megacli

In the MegaRAID SAS Software User Guide it is stated that a Drive Group includes one or more virtual drives. An excerpt from the document is:

"A virtual drive is a partition in a drive group that is made up of contiguous data segments on the drives. A virtual drive can consist of these components:

- an entire drive group
- more than one entire drive group
- a part of a drive group
- parts of more than one drive group
- a combination of any two of these conditions."

My first question is the following: How can I create a drive group and inside that group have more than one virtual drive ?

In the User Guide there is just one relevant command, regarding drive groups. The guide says that this command creates a new drive group:

```
MegaCli –CfgLDAdd -RX[E0:S0,E1:S1,...] [WT | WB] [NORA | RA] [Direct |
Cached] [CachedBadBBU|NoCachedBadBBU] [-szXXX [-szYYY ...]] [-strpszM]
[-Hsp[E0:S0,...]] [-AfterLdX] | -Force [FDE|CtrlBased] [-Cache] [-enblPI
-val] -aN
```

In my opinion, running this command does not create a drive group.

My second question: Is a RAID Array the same thing as a Drive Group, in MegaRAID ? 
I am assuming they are the same thing.

What I actually want to achieve is to create a RAID Array , and in that array more than one virtual volumes.

Answer (score 1):

Drive group is essentially idea/concept. For instance, if you create RAID 1. You have two drives that make up this RAID 1. Two drives are `Drive group`. On those two drives you can have one or more `virtual drives`. Virtual drive can be considered as partition on this RAID 1 array / Drive group. If you want single virtual drive with maximum size (size of drive in drive group) you would do something like

> megacli -CfgLdAdd -r1 [252:0,252:1] WB RA Direct CachedBadBBU -a0

however if you want to split your **Drive Group** in two virtual drives you can do it like this

> megacli -CfgLdAdd -r1 [252:0,252:1] WB RA Direct CachedBadBBU -sz500GB -a0
>
> megacli -CfgLdAdd -r1 [252:0,252:1] WB RA Direct CachedBadBBU -sz500GB -a0

These commands would create RAID 1 of drives in Enclosure 252, slot 0 and 1 with
writeback enabled, readahead enabled, direct I/O cache policy, still use controller cache if battery goes bad (possibly trouble) and size (`-sz500GB`) as option if you want to use less than maximum space and have *multiple virtual drives* in *drive group*